# page navigation identification with images

Tags: php, html, image

I have a navigation on my page with elements, about us, what we do, clients, contact us and so on..... all these are images only. not text. i can recognize which page is selected based on the value of $selected. When $selected==about, then i want the default image of about us to be something like about_selected.png and likewise for everything else. how can i achieve this? i tried javascript but could no get it right. here is a sample code from my page:

```
<a href="about.php" class="<?php if($selected =="about"){echo 'selected';}?>" onmouseover="document.about.src='images/About_over.png'" onmouseout="document.about.src='images/About.png'" ><img src="images/About.png" alt="about us" name="about" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="we_do.php" class="<?php if($selected =="do"){echo 'selected';}?>"  onmouseover="document.wedo.src='images/Wedo_over.png'" onmouseout="document.wedo.src='images/Wedo.png'" ><img src="images/Wedo.png" alt="what we do" name="wedo"/></a></li>
```

Comment: you should assign an `id` to your `<img>` elements, then use `document.getElementById('id').src`

Comment: formatting your code to not require a horizontal scrollbar would be helpful for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in your own code.

```
<img src="images/About<?php if($selected =="about"){echo '_selected';}?>.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider CSS for these mouseover effects instead of the inline JavaScript you are using here. A List Apart has [some useful information](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/) on that.

The 'selected' class can be used to trigger a third 'active' state on the background image. I do suggest that you put a text in between the  tags to make sure search engines can index your navigation. You can use CSS again to make the actual text not visible (negative text-indent usually is the way to go)